# How to dynamically convert any given SQL/HQL select query to equivalent count query?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, nhibernate, hql

I want to convert any given select query into equivalent count query. The select query can be a valid SQL or HQL query. Following is my attempt.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts select query into equivalent count query
    /// </summary>
    protected string ConvertToCountQuery(string selectQuery)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectQuery))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        string[] selectParts = selectQuery.ToLower().Split(new string[] { "select" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string[] fromParts = selectParts[0].Split(new string[] { "from" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        selectParts[0] = string.Format("select count(*) from{0}", fromParts[1]);
        return string.Concat(selectParts);
    }
```

It works fine for SQL queries because they are case-insensitive however, for HQL queries it loses the case. How can I preserve the case while still getting the equivalent count query.

Sample test data for SQL:

```
select u.username, u.email, u.first_name, u.last_name from users u where u.username like '% %';
```

Expected output for SQL:

```
select count(*) from users u where u.username like '% %';
```

Sample test data for HQL:

```
select u.Username, u.Email, u.FirstName, u.LastName from User u where u.Username like '% %';
```

Expected output for HQL:

```
select count(*) from Users u where u.Username like '% %';
```

Note the case sensitivity in HQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've found the solution myself.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts select query into equivalent count query
    /// </summary>
    public static string ConvertToCountQuery(string selectQuery)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectQuery) || !selectQuery.ToLower().Contains("select"))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    return string.Concat(
            "select count(*)",
            selectQuery.Substring(selectQuery.ToLower().IndexOf(" from")));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work when the query has a group by clause. It neither works when it contains subqueries in the select clause (with another from clause, but not the from clause you are looking for).

Comment: @StefanSteinegger I understand what you mean by the group by case, can you please explain what you mean by 'select clause (with another from clause..'? Can you give a test query?

Comment: As in the reference docs (search for subqueries): `select cat.id, (select max(kit.weight) from cat.kitten kit)
from Cat as cat`

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting the given query into a subquery:

```
var countQuery = string.Format("select count(*) from ({0})", selectQuery);
```

It would turn it into this kind of query:

```
select count(*) from (select ... from User u where u.Username like '% %');
```

I don't know if it works. Oracle needs to support this (subqueries in the FROM clause). HQL needs to support it as well (it's usually quite transparent in many things, so there is hope). If it doesn't, I would consider it as not possible with reasonable effort and acceptable reliability.

Consider using linq or query over for these kind of tasks, since these APIs are much more flexible in reliably building queries at runtime. AFAIK, both have built in count support.